# How to multiply two matrices with only one loop in Java?

Tags: java, matrix, matrix-multiplication

This is the traditional method I've found using 3 "for" loops.

```
    public int [][] multiMatrices(int[][] m1, int [][] m2){

    int fil_m1 = m1.length;
    int col_m1 = m1[0].length;

//  int fil_m2 = m2.length;     //NOT NECESSARY
    int col_m2 = m2[0].length;

    int [][] end = new int [fil_m1][col_m2];

    for (int x=0; x < end.length; x++) {
         for (int y=0; y < end[x].length; y++) {
            for (int z=0; z<col_m1; z++) {
              end[x][y] += m1[x][z]*m2[z][y]; 
            }
         }
    }
    return end;
}
```

I am now trying to obtain the same result, but the goal is to use only one "for". For the sake of the exercise I can't use any external library. I've found something called the Strassen algorithm, it may or may not help.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (int x=0,y=0,z=0; x < end.length ; z++) {

              if(z==col_m1) {z=0;y++;}                
              if(y==end[x].length){y=0;x++;}
              end[x][y] += m1[x][z]*m2[z][y]; 
         }
    }
```

Comment: The `end.length` here is the total count of the elements in the matrix right ?

Comment: end[x].length is number of elements in 1D, end.length must be 2D. So, yes.